# Item "Open in Notepad" in Windows Explorer like in a Notepad ++

Tags: windows-explorer, notepad++

I know this can be done using the registry, but I do not know what values need to be changed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRK5T.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Open regedit and go to the key **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell**
Right-Click the key and add a new key named  **“Open with Notepad.”**
Right-Click your new key and add another key named **"command"**
Select your new **"command"** key and then open the properties of the **"(default)"** value in the right-hand window.
Next enter **"notepad.exe %1"** in the **"Value data:"** box and click **"OK"**.

Close the registry editor and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to creating a top-level context menu entry is to add a shortcut to **Notepad** in the **SendTo** folder. The shortcuts in this folder populate the `Send To` context menu. I've always used this approach not only for **Notepad**, but also Hex Editors and Resource Hacker. A simple shortcut does the trick, no worries about command line syntax.

1. Open **Explorer**, click in the Address bar, and type `shell:SendTo`. This opens the **SendTo** folder.

[image]

2. Create a shortcut to the desired application using the New Shortcut wizard or drag-and-drop from the Start Menu.
3. Check the context menu & test its functionality.

[image]